# Launch url on Java by command line

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I have a issue for this code . Please help me review :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start chrome " + url);
```

This code is OK if I launch the url which does not contain parameter, but i put parameter to this url,the link does not work and dont see parameter on url. thanks

Comment: Paste the url that is causing the problem. I think the problem may be due to not escaping back slashes.

Comment: This url runs on local. Example : http://127.0.0.1/acb/display.do?user=abc&password=123

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
Desktop.getDesktop.browse(uri);
```

Comment: This code uses for default browser.I want to launch url on multiple browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start chrome \"" + url + "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

The url contains various symbols that cmd may think illegal to use. For example

```
 cd new folder
```

is illegal as there is a space between so u must use

```
cd "new folder"
```

Just the same you must enclose the url in "" to make it work. Thus you must use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start chrome \"" + url + "\"");
```

Or use this to directly launch the url in default browser:

```
Desktop.getDesktop.browse(uri);
```

Note wherever there is a \ in the url you must use \\ in place of it. So that java doesnot mistakes it as an escape sequence.

Comment: *"So wherever there is a / in the url you must use // in place of it."*  No, that is only the case for back-slash (\\).